# I m trying to access google places api with following url but unable to get results

Tags: ios

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=api_key

but unfortunately i m inable to get the result and it displays an error message:
{
  "error_message": "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 106.67.62.253, with empty referer",
  "html_attributions": [],
  "results": [],
  "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: did you try READING the error message? you're not allowed to hit the api from whatever IP you're using.

Comment: Error message is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You need create a project from **google developer console**. [link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/) OR [link 2](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_ios_backend,placesios&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_IOS&reusekey=true&pli=1)   add create a new Project, add credential, get API and Enable 
location service. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPDnW.jpg) may help for you.